# CSS Sprites - How to leave Hover button in depressed state

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-sprites, sprite

CSS Sprites (button) with three different states:

1. Standard
2. Hover
3. Pressed (active)

Currently "Standard", "Hover", and "Pressed" work.  The issue is, "Pressed" only stays pressed as the mouse is held down. I would like the "Pressed," or active, state to stay active until it is clicked again.  Any ideas?  CSS solution?  javascript solution?

Thanks for your help,
D

Here's the code:

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">

    a.button {
        background-image: url('BUTTON SPRITES IMAGE');
        width: 86px;
        height: 130px;
        display: block;
        text-indent: -9999px;

    }

    a.micbutton:hover { 
        background-position: 0 -130px;

    }

    a.micbutton:active { 
        background-position: 0 -260px; 

    }

</style>

<a class="button" href="#" ></a>

</html>
```

Comment: Leaving `:hover` or `:active` enabled after leaving the element or letting go of the mouse button is not possible with CSS alone. You will have to add a JavaScript click event to maintain the _active_ style and handle the _second_ click to disable it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help - tremendously awesome.  It ends up being a combo of new CSS classes and javascript.  This new code allows the 3 states mentioned above (Normal, Hover, Pressed).  When the "Pressed" state is clicked again, the (sprites) button appears back at its normal state.

Here is the final code:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('button').toggleClass('button1').toggleClass('active');
});   
});

</script>   

<style type="text/css">

a.button {
    background-image: url('BUTTON SPRITES IMAGE');
    width: 86px;
    height: 130px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;

}

a.button:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -130px;

}

a.button:active, a.active { 
    background-position: 0 -260px; 

}

a.button1:active { 
background-position: 0 -260px; 

}

</style>

<a class="button" href="#" ></a>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

add an active class:

```
a.button {
    background-image: url('BUTTON SPRITES IMAGE');
    width: 86px;
    height: 130px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;

}

a.button:hover { 
    background-position: 0 -130px;
}

a.button:active, a.active { 
    background-position: 0 -260px; 
}
```

Then when your button is active simply add the class:

```
<a class="button active" href="#" ></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an active class was correct. Using the toggleClass on click function adds the active class and removes class on second click. This is what you were after I believe.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdNfT/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });    
});
```

Comment: +1 for the correct solution and what I was about to write :-)